# Is it possible to close a TcpListener in Tokio?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a `tokio_core::net::TcpListener` that I create and then call the `incoming` method on to get a stream of incoming connections. I then use the `for_each` method on that stream to turn it into a future and run the future on an event loop. Once I do that is there any way to unbind from the port at some later time?

If not, is there any other API in Tokio that can be used to create a TCP server which can be closed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, you need to drop the `TcpListener` / the `Future` returned by `for_each`.

You could:

- Write a `Future` implementation for some struct containing the rest of your application's state. The `Future::poll` implementation for your struct then `poll`s all the contained `Future` states, and returns `Async::Ready` if you want to exit early.  It might help performance if the contained `Future`s are wrapped in [`oneshot::spawn`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/futures/sync/oneshot/fn.spawn.html) to run in their own task.

  Your struct would contain an `Option<SpawnHandle<(), ...>>`. If you want to stop listening just set it to `None`.
- Filter the `incoming` stream by checking some "global" (`Arc<AtomicBool>`) flag whether to continue listening using [`Stream::take_while`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.take_while)
- Check at the end of your `for_each` handler whether to continue listening and return an error otherwise (which stops the `for_each` loop)

The latter two methods only stop after seeing/handling an incoming connection, so they only work in a busy environment.

Comment: How do you drop the `TcpListener` / the `Future` returned by `for_each` if you have passed that to `core.run(future)`?  :-/

Answer (score 5):

Here's another option I recently found out about.

You basically need to drop the `TcpListener`/`for_each` future to stop listening. Since it never completes on its own, simply combine it with another future you control (e.g. a `oneshot::Receiver<()>`) using `select()`. The returned future will complete if either the listener completes (never) or the oneshot receives a value (which you can trigger by sending something into the other end).

For more complex programs which need to shut down multiple things, there is also a [`watch` channel](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.5.0/tokio/sync/index.html#watch-channel) with one `Sender` and multiple `Receiver<()>`s.

There are also suggestions to [make this easier in the futures crate itself](https://github.com/alexcrichton/futures-rs/pull/696).